# Opera/Firefox Javascript engine differences

Tags: javascript, firefox, opera

I wanted to know if anyone else has experienced this 'glitch' between browsers with javascript.

My javascript was the following

```
  var theForm = document.getElementById( 'theForm' );

  theForm.firstname = theForm.firstName.value.trim();
  theForm.lastname = theForm.lastName.value.trim();


  theForm.firstName.style.color = "red";
```

This doesn't seem to be working in Opera 11 but it works in Firefox 4.

I just think that the two javascript engines are handling things differently.

When I debug the javascript in both I get different results to.

In Opera, theForm.firstName turns into a regular old string after assignment but in Firefox it stays a form element.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Well they are 2 different types of browsers....

Comment: What your doing is evil / broken

Comment: @Matt McDonald? Isn't it pretty obvious from the code? He's trying to trim the values in fields firstname and lastname, then set the text color of firstName to red. Having said that, I can't stand it when people say, this isn't working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form id="bar">
  <input name="foo">
</form>

var form = document.getElementById("bar");

form.foo; // is a DOM element

form.foo = form.foo.value.trim(); // trying to set a dom element to a string??

form.foo; // What am I?
```

How is a  browser supposed to know whether form["someName"] is a property or a DOM element inside the form if you shadow it.

Garbage in, Garbage out.

Comment: yeah, it's just weird that it works in firefox. i guess they 'account' for it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Raynos said: You're setting a DOM element to a string. Change your code to be

```
var theForm = document.getElementById( 'theForm' );
theForm.firstname.value = theForm.firstName.value.trim();
theForm.lastname.value = theForm.lastName.value.trim();
theForm.firstName.style.color = "red";
```